# Angular - Using one controller for many coherent views across multiple HTTP requests

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a simple Angular JS scenario. I show a list of experts in one view, and that list contains actions to edit an expert, which would be done in another view. These views are coming from server and are not in one file. They don't load together.

```
<!-- experts.html -->
<div ng-controller='expertController'>
    <!-- showing the list of experts here -->
</div>
```

And in another file on the server I have:

```
<!-- expert.html -->
<div ng-controller='expertController'>
    <!-- a form to edit/add an expert -->
</div>
```

And my controller is:

```
app.controller('expertController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.getExperts = function () {
        _.get('/expert/getexperts/', null, function (data) {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.experts = data;
            });
        });
    };

    $scope.editExpert = function (index) {
        _.get('/expert/getexpert/', { id: $scope.experts[index].Id }, function (data) {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.expert = data;
                });
         });
    };
});
```

However, no data would be shown in the edit form. I inspected scopes using Batarang, but `expert` object won't be shown.

The problem seems to be that I use one controller for two (and optionally more than two) views. However, as I've read some other questions on SO, it seems that the best practice is to have one controller per HTML view.

However, I think it's more coherent and consistent to have one `expertController` to do all CRUD operations, alongside other actions related to `expert`. I think it's a little ugly to have `expertEditController` for edit form and `expertListController` for the list HTML.

What is the best practice here? How can I have a coherent and semantically named controller, and at the same time support many views. In any MVC framework that I've seen till now, it's something routine to support many views via one controller.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint at `$scope.expert = data;` to check it's called with the correct data.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Of course you can use many `views` with the same `controller`.
For example: for editing and adding new items.

But you have to remember that each time the view is loaded the **controller is initialized** and fresh, new `$scope` is injected.

In your case it would be better to just use two separate controllers (one for `experts` and one for `expert`) and use -- optionally -- some service to communicate between those and maybe provide some caching mechanism.

**UPDATE** In case you want to provide some common/shared functionality between controllers the best way to go is to create and then `inject` a separate service. It keeps the code DRY.

Comment: So, what about coherency? OP asks to see how he can have a better named controller that does whatever related to expert. What you offered results in bad naming again.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati One controller is for `expert` and one is for the list of `experts`. CRUD operations themselves should/can be injected to both as a separate service.  I find it quite coherent.

Comment: @artur u said "Of course you can use many views with the same controller. For example: for editing and adding new items."Could u plz provide an example .

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example project (not created by me) that illustrates how to use a single controller with two views: one for showing a list of items and one for editing or adding a single item: http://embed.plnkr.co/jAK31F/

The basic principle used in the controller is to check whether an id of a single item has been passed and run the applicable logic for that situation:

```
controllers.controller('MainController', function( $scope, $location, $routeParams, ItemService)  {
  if ($routeParams.itemid) {
    // do stuff for single item
    if ($routeParams.itemid == 0) {
      // do stuff for adding item
    } else {
      // do stuff for editing item
    }
  } else {
    // do stuff for listing multiple items
  }
});
```

The different views are configured in the routes like so:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        // routes
        $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'item_list.html',
            controller: 'MainController'
        }).
        when('/:itemid', {
            templateUrl: 'item_single.html',
            controller: 'MainController'
        });
    }]);
```

So an url like `baseurl/` will open the list view, and an url like `baseurl/1` will open the detail view of the item with id 1.

With regard to this being a best practice or not, for most situations I don't think this method offers an advantage over using two controllers: one for the list, and one for a single item. In my experience a controller to view multiple items has different concerns than one for editing a single item. Any shared logic can be placed in a service as suggested in earlier answers.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when we use same controller for other view, it will reloads that controller whenever the view loads. At that moment scope will lose it's data.To avoid this i used $rootScope instead of $scope. I don't know whether this approach is correct or not but it works.

$rootScope.expert instead of $scope.expert.

Comment: Sure it works but for sharing data across the application services/factories should be used. Putting stuff on the $rootScope can be very expensive in regards to the performance.

Comment: @AleksandarBencun Yes you are correct later I also cleared that services/factories should be used in this case. throwing more values into $rootScope could decrease the application performance and it is not at all useful.